# Core Data Migration "Failed to unlink support directory"

Tags: ios, core-data

I have the following log entry when using Automatic Migration:

```
Failed to unlink support directory 
/..Test.sqlite_SUPPORT from old store location: /.Test.sqlite.migrationdestination due to 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x15e7f830 {NSUnderlyingError=0x15e7a850 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory", NSFilePath=/..Test.sqlite_SUPPORT, NSUserStringVariant=(
                    Remove
        )
```

However the migration does not fail. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: I had the same issue with lightweight automatic migration.

Comment: Did find out the reason or a way to resolve it?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: No unfortunately not.